# Having single SQLConnection across entire asp.net website or having invidiual connections for per DB query

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, sqlconnection, sqlclient

Ok my question requires pretty much expertise on this stuff

I want you to compare these 2 classes. First one opens a new connection for each query while the other one keeps 1 connection open and for other thousands of concurrent queries uses same connection

**Now which one is better why ?**

**What are the cons and pros ?**

Asp.net , .net 4.5 website , c#

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class DbConnection
{
    public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=my_DB;uid=sa;pwd=my_PW;";

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        if (strQuery.Length < 5)
            return dSet;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
                {
                    DA.Fill(dSet);
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }catch(Exception){}

        return dSet;
    }
}
```

And here the single connection across all threads , across entire website

```
using System;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class DbConnection
{
    private static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=my_DB;uid=sa;pwd=my_PW;";

    private static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString);

    static DbConnection()
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        if (strQuery.Length < 5)
            return dSet;
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
            {
                DA.Fill(dSet);
            }

            return dSet;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return dSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not the second one, you will get threads trying to use the same connection at the same time, which may or may not be open.   You should at least have a connection per request.

Comment: @BenRobinson ty so it is better to have individual connection for each DB query right ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be per query, but you don't want a single static connection used by threads from different requests, you will get in a horrible mess, it will just fail all the time, seemingly at random.

Comment: Agree with Ben - the second option would be terrible. it is not thread safe and it won't scale under load.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to have a read up on is [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

Out of the two options you have given, option 1 is the better as you are disposing the connection as soon as you are done with it. Combine this with Connection Pooling, which is usually enabled in ADO.NET by default, the disposed connection will not actually be closed but returned to the pool so that it can be used again by another request. Therefore you will find that option 1 will far out perform option 2 when it comes to a large amount of concurrent requests.